# Prismatic Afterglow Controller Headphone Jack Issue (Xbox One)

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

While using a Beats Studio3 headphones on the Afterglow Controller, it gets automatically disconnected (not physically... lol) or unrecognized by the controller, then I unplug & plug again (only works again with the controller-cable)

While talking with people on a party chat, I can’t hear anything whether In game or in chat, except that I can still talk and they hear me, so only the mic works.

This didn’t happen when I started to use these headphones on the controller, but I realized that I had usually done something that might have been wrong during all this time... I left the headphone wire connected to the controller when I was done playing, so I could only disconnect my headphones and go (turning everything off).

I know the problem is on the controller, because I tried different headphones and they were fine.

I set up different configurations on the controller and sound and nothing.

I tried my Beats headphones (wired) on a different device and the cable is fine.

So, assuming that there is something wrong with the controller, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have a wired Afterglow controller, and I am using my Studio3 Beats Headphones that are wired to the controller.  Basically what I did is that on the xbox one, there is an app for Afterglow, called "Afterglow" all you need to do is update your controller (if it is needed) and scroll all the way to the right of the app and there should be some sliders that have labels such as "Volume, mixer" etc

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It solved my kids inability to hear the chat & I never would have known bto download an app because there was nothing in the package that mentioned it.